# While parsing input as JSON and persisting, only firsts JSON object is persisted

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to read array of JSON posted to a topic that my pipeline is subscribed to and persist the same to BigQuery. The problem I face while doing so is that it persists only the first object, can someone please provide me insight on what I am doing wrong here.

```
    /** A DoFn that converts a table row from JSON into a BigQuery table row. */
  static class FormatAsTableRowFn extends DoFn<TableRow, TableRow> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    static TableSchema getSchema() {
        return new TableSchema().setFields(new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>() {
              // Compose the list of TableFieldSchema from tableSchema.
              {
                add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("PillBoxID").setType("STRING").setMode("NULLABLE"));
                add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Period").setType("STRING").setMode("NULLABLE"));
                add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Time").setType("TIMESTAMP").setMode("NULLABLE"));
                add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("IsTaken").setType("STRING").setMode("NULLABLE"));
              }
        });
      }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        TableRow jsonRow = c.element();
        // Setup a date formatter to parse the date appropriately
          SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        try {

            TableRow bQueryRow = new TableRow()
             .set("PillBoxID", (String) jsonRow.get("PillBoxID"))
             .set("Period", (String) jsonRow.get("Period"))
             .set("Time",ft.format(ft.parse((String) jsonRow.get("Time"))))
             .set("IsTaken", (String) jsonRow.get("IsTaken"));
             LOG.error("Inside try" + bQueryRow.getF()); 
          c.output(bQueryRow);

       } catch (ParseException pe) {
           LOG.error("ParseException");     
           LOG.error(pe.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

and my pipleline code is as shown below,

```
    bigQueryPipeLine
    .apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic(options.getPubsubTopic()).withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new FormatAsTableRowFn()))
    .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to(tableSpec)
        .withSchema(FormatAsTableRowFn.getSchema()));
```

Comment: That code looks reasonable.  Have you looked at the Dataflow monitoring UI in the Developer Console?  You can see there how much data each transform in your pipeline has processed.  There is also a link from there to Cloud Logging, where you can see if you are getting ParseExceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to process multiple records if you format the input JSON to include an array of items.

Example input:

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {"PillBoxID":"ID5", "Period":"Morning", "Time":"2016-03-14T11:11:11", "IsTaken":"true"},
        {"PillBoxID":"ID6", "Period":"Afternoon", "Time":"2016-03-14T15:11:11", "IsTaken":"false"}
    ]
}
```

The rough example processElement() code adds the 2 items to c.output() for later storage in BigQuery.

```
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws DatastoreException, IOException{
        TableRow jsonRowObj = c.element();
        LOG.info("Original input:" + c.element().toPrettyString());
        ArrayList<Map> jsonRows = (ArrayList<Map>)jsonRowObj.get("items");
        Iterator<Map> iterator = jsonRows.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map jsonRow =  (Map)iterator.next();
            // Setup a date formatter to parse the date appropriately
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                LOG.info("child input JSON: "+jsonRow.toString());
                TableRow bQueryRow = new TableRow()
                 .set("PillboxID", (String) jsonRow.get("PillBoxID"))
                 .set("Period", (String) jsonRow.get("Period"))
                 .set("Time",ft.format(ft.parse((String) jsonRow.get("Time"))))
                 .set("IsTaken", (boolean) Boolean.parseBoolean((String)jsonRow.get("IsTaken")));

              c.output(bQueryRow);

           } catch (ParseException pe) {
               LOG.error("");   
               LOG.error("ParseException " +pe.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```